# how to use software decoder in video streaming like mxplayer

Tags: android, android-videoview, vitamio

i am trying to play this stream [link](http://s1.wssiptv.com:8000/live/WSSiptv.com/soer8uwsoerijf42098trewiods/37.ts?1234).

on mxplayer its working only when i set the decoder to software decoder , but when i try to play it on "vitamio" or on normal video view its not working , is there anyway to enable the software decoder in my project 
thanks in advance